# How to use CTRL + R in CMD when using Microsoft Power Automate

Tags: cmd.exe, automation, webex, microsoft-power-automate-desktop

I have made a flow in Microsoft Power Automate. It is a large one hence can't post it here.

It opens Chrome and clicks on a link and joins a Webex meeting. I want the flow to run at a scheduled time but don't have power automate premium.

I have found out workaround to do this. I have made a CMD session which opens the Main Power Automate page and my flow is selected by default. I just have to send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> command to the app and it will run the flow. How should I send the key to the app with cmd.

The script is a short one:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Power Automate Desktop
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Power Automate Desktop\PAD.Console.Host.exe"
```

If this way is not possible then can anyone suggest another way to easily accomplish this task?

Comment: Does `PAD.Console.Host.exe` not have any command line parameters for this _(try `PAD.Console.Host.exe /?`, `PAD.Console.Host.exe -help`, etc.)_?

Comment: What would this result in ?

Comment: To determine if the `.exe` supports a command-line parameter that allows opening/running a specific flow by default.

Comment: not directly from cmd.exe but this article shows a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709474/sendkeys-from-command-prompt